# Прибавка к date и time

Tags: php, дата, время

Всем привет, прощу помощи.

```
    $u_data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + $_POST['Date'] * (24 * 60 * 60));
```

Должно прибавлять 24 часа к дате при введённом в input value 1, а оно прибавляет 20 часов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пж)

Т.е На данный момент 06.11.2018 02:37:22 при запросе оно добавляет в базу значение 06.11.2018 23:37:22

Comment: Единица которую вы прибавляете это одна секунда.  Заменил плюс на умножение: $u_data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + $_POST['Date'] * (24 * 60 * 60)); Теперь оно добавит день, но разница о которой вы пишите сохранится, т.е 4 часа. Прочтите мой ответ, вам надо установить таймзону

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Настройте таймзону на сервере.

Вот это выведет дату по гринвичу: (не вариант если устанавливаете правильную таймзону)

```
$u_data = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + $_POST['Date'] + (24 * 60 * 60));
```

Если невозможно сконфигурировать сервер, то эта функция установит таймзону **на время** выполнения скрипта:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
```

> пхп документация: date_default_timezone_set — Устанавливает временную зону по умолчанию
>   для всех функций даты/времени в скрипте

Рекомендую или работать с датами по гринвичу и только. Либо во всех скриптах устанавливать свою таймзону.

Comment: Либо я глуп, либо ничего не изменилось(

Comment: Вот сам запрос

else if (isset($_POST ['add'])) 
{
    $mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER 'utf8'");
    $u_user = $_POST['User'];
    $u_key = $_POST['Key'];
    date_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
  $u_data = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + $_POST['Date'] * (24 * 60 * 60));
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `CheatBase` (`User`, `Key`, `Date`) VALUES ('$u_user', '$u_key', '$u_data')");
    header("Location: /main");
}

Comment: Все ок, gmdate не смотрит на тайм зону. Сделайте все тоже самое, с установкой таймзоны и date вместо dmdate

Comment: date_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow'); $u_data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + $_POST['Date'] * (24 * 60 * 60));

Comment: Спасибо! Вы супер)))
Нужно было - date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
А не date_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');

Comment: Поправил ответ, может еще кому пригодится